# Font issue on Mac - Android Studio Electric Eel

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been having a font problem since I updated to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 . The editor font is normal, but the menu font looks pixelated. How can i solve this?

I'm using Apple MacBook Pro 14 - M1 Pro.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Kni.png) 
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPvsg.png)

**Edit:**

**Hi, I solved the problem. Go to Android Studio Preferences -> Preferences | Appearance & Behavior -> Antialiasing -> both of IDE and Editor must be Grayscale**

[image: Solved]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. Go to Android Studio Preferences -> Preferences | Appearance & Behavior -> Antialiasing -> both of IDE and Editor must be Grayscale. Thanks!

[image]